# Collection view embed in container view does'nt work properly in iOS 8 - items are invisble

Tags: ios8, xcode6, collectionview

I have  a collection view which is embed in container view and therefore in another view controller.
Using Xcode 6 my collection view is displayed without items (they are invisible in spite of fact that datasource has been already provided collection view with necessary data).
Reveal app shows me invisible cells.
And I can select cells - only in this case they are visible, but only one cell.
Also I tried to build my app for iOS 7 on Xcode 6 - I still have the problem.
Using Xcode 5.1.1 I don't have such problem - everything works like a charm.